# Passing response data to an array

Tags: javascript

How can I pass fetched data to array called users? I've tried using this.users = data.data, then console.log(users) and nothing is showing up.

Also I am trying to map response, I am getting error in console `Uncaught TypeError: fetchData.map is not a function`

```
const users = [];

const fetchData = () => {
    axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users')
  .then(({data}) => {
    this.users = data.data;
    console.log(data);
  })
}
fetchData();

const mapUsers = fetchData.map((item) => {
    return {
        avatar: item.avatar
    }
})
```

Comment: `users.push(data)`  And you can't `map` over a function.  `map` is an array method.

Comment: additionally, this: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: This is a bit of a mess. What is the data you're getting from /api/users? What is the expected result and the actual result, besides the error you're getting?

Comment: I do nto get an error from fetching data. I have error when trying to map fetchData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you would need to move map inside to the callback

```js
let users = [];

const fetchData = () => {
  axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users").then(({ data }) => {
    users = data.data;

    const mapUsers = users.map((item) => {
      return {
        avatar: item.avatar,
      };
    });
    console.log("mapUsers", mapUsers);
  });
};

fetchData();
```

or

```js
let users = [];

const fetchData = () => {
  return axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users").then(({ data }) => {
    return data.data;
  });
};

fetchData().then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
  const mapUsers = data.map((item) => {
    return {
      avatar: item.avatar,
    };
  });

  console.log("mapUsers", mapUsers);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, worked. Idk why people in comments were saying this was a mess.

Comment: @Dave because your code was rather confusing, you did a lot of unnecessary steps